# Pass PHP value to Javascript While They Are in Different Documents

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables

I would like to create an upload form. In the form, member can upload multiple pictures to his/her own folder, which is named by the member's ID. For example, if the member's ID is 0001, then he/she can upload his pictures to **image/0001/** folder.

In the uploading form, I use Javascript to let users upload multiple pictures in the same page. After user select the first picture, it generates the second **`<input type="file">`** ; after selecting the 2nd picture, it generates the third **`<input type="file">`**.... and so on.

Now, I want to add constraint that each member can have at most 5 pictures in their folder. Therefore, I use a PHP variable **$pic_in_folder** to to count how many picture the member has already had in the his/her folder.

```js
// test.js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var pic_in_folder      //To receive PHP variable $pic_in_folder
  var blockCount = 1;    //To count how many #upload_block.
  $("body").on("change", "#picture", function(){
    //if( pic_in_folder + blockCount < 5 ){
      $("#upload_block" + blockCount ).after($("<div/>", {
        id: "upload_block"+ (blockCount + 1),
          class: "upload_block",
        style: "margin: 1rem;"
      }).fadeIn("slow").append($("<input/>", {
        name: "picture[]",
        type: "file",
        id: "picture"
      })));
      blockCount += 1;
    //}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Upload Picture</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
    $member_Id = $_GET["member"];
    $pic_in_folder = 0;  //Count how many pictures this member currently have
    foreach(glob("picture/".$member_Id."/*") as $file){
      if(file_exists($file)){
        $pic_in_folder += 1;
      }
    }
    ?>

    <h3>You currently have <?php echo $pic_in_folder; ?> pictures.</h3>
    <hr/>
    <form name="upload_form">
      <div id="upload_block1" class="upload_block" style="margin: 1rem;">
        <input type="file" name="picture[]" id="picture" />
      </div>

      <input type="submit" />

    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

For the Javascript codes, in order to avoid member having more than 5 pictures after they uploading pictures, I use variable **pic_in_folder** to get values from PHP variable **$pic_in_folder** ; **blockCount** to count how many input block is showing in the form. And the Javascript only generates input block when (**pic_in_folder** + **blockCount**) < 5

However, My HTML & PHP codes are in one document and the Javascript is in the other one. How can I pass the **$pic_in_folder** to the Javascript document variables ?

Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the Variable for JS in your PHP-File:

```
echo '<script>var pic_in_folder = ' . $pic_in_folder . '</script>';
```

This will make it available globally. Then you can just use `pic_in_folder` in your other JS file. But be sure to include your external JS AFTER you did the script-tag above, so the external file actually knows about the variable.

Regarding best practices, I'm not sure if this is a good approach but it worked for me in one of my projects. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `hidden` field to store the `$pic_in_folder` value.

```
<input type="hidden" id="pic_in_folder" name="pic_in_folder" value="<?php echo $pic_in_folder;?>" />
```

Then read this value in JavaScript as follows:

```
var pic_in_folder = $("#pic_in_folder").val();
```

Comment: Noshii's solution is another approach.

Comment: Thank you !!
This might also be a special solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 <?php
        $member_Id = $_GET["member"];
        $pic_in_folder = 0;  //Count how many pictures this member currently have
        foreach(glob("picture/".$member_Id."/*") as $file){
          if(file_exists($file)){
            $pic_in_folder += 1;
          }
        }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Upload Picture</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
           function picsInFolder() { return <?= $pic_in_folder;?>; }
        </script>
        <script src="/test.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>


        <h3>You currently have <?php echo $pic_in_folder; ?> pictures.</h3>
        <hr/>
        <form name="upload_form">
          <div id="upload_block1" class="upload_block" style="margin: 1rem;">
            <input type="file" name="picture[]" id="picture" />
          </div>

          <input type="submit" />

        </form>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Then in your JS file you can call picsInFolder();

```
var pic_in_folder  = picsInFolder();
```